# .hide() and .show() not working on mobile app

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile

i m coding a mobile application with jquery and framework7.
I have a products.html page, in a listview i m listing products, in li tags i have data-category data, i want to filter products with checkboxes, codes are;

```
<li data-category="red"><input type="checkbox" value="red">red</li>
<li data-category="white"><input type="checkbox" value="white">white</li>
```

and in my custom.js file;

```
    myApp.onPageInit('products', function (page) {
    getRss(urlProducts,'#products');

    $$('input').on('click', function (e) {
        var category = $$(this).val();
        var check = $$(this).prop('checked');
        filter(name,check);
    });
});

function filter(category, check)
{
    if(check == true) {

        $$('*[data-category="'+category+'"').show();

    }
    else if (check == false)
    {
        $$('*[data-category="'+ category +'"]').hide();
    }
}
```

this is working in opera and chrome very nice but when i build app and install or when i use phonegap desktop application, hide and show functions are not working on mobile phone.
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: @guradio: you can overwrite the jquery selector as well.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar this selector is not working on mobile phone $$('input').on('click', function (e) { what is the true style?